# Как закруглить края кнопки, которая не имеет рамки и полностью состоит из изображения?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, сигналы-слоты, qlabel

Я сделал кнопку с картинкой с помощью модуля *PyQt5*. В таблице стиля убрал рамку, и теперь **`кнопка состоит только из картинки`**.

Теперь **`я хочу скруглить края у этой кнопки`**.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это сделать?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()

button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
button.setStyleSheet('''QPushButton {
                            border: none;
                            margin: 0px;
                            padding: 0px;
                        }''')
button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('picture1.png'))
button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 140))

box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
box.addWidget(button)
window.setLayout(box)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, через кликабельную `QLabel`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Label(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, antialiasing=True, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Antialiasing = antialiasing
        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 70 

        self.target = QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(Qt.transparent)    

        p = QPixmap("head2.jpg").scaled(  
            140, 140, Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QPainter(self.target)
        if self.Antialiasing:
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(
            0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit() 


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.label = Label(self)
        self.label.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: green;")     

    def onClicked(self):
        print('Вы сделали клил')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Очень большой и сложный для меня код, сейчас буду разбирать. Я почему-то думал, что это можно делать гораздо проще. Никогда бы сам не догадался. Т.е. такого резльтата нельзя добиться таблицами стиля?

Comment: Просто в дальнейшем я хотел сделать протенькую анимацию при нажатии - изменение размера. Нашел, как делают это для кнопок. Это можно будет реализовать потом для QLabel?

Comment: @MAXIM045 это наверное самый простой вариант, после варианта отображения круглого изображения :)

Comment: @MAXIM045 пробуйте если не получится задавайте вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо большое вам еще раз!

Comment: Cейчас  разбирал код. Очень много нового узнал, не знаю, что делал бы без вас:)

Comment: @MAXIM045  `PyQt5` - это сила. Дерзайте!