# Почему метод QPixmap модуля PyQt5 не принимает в качестве аргумента переменную, содержащую строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Недавно я задавал здесь вопрос - [Как закруглить края кнопки, которая не имеет рамки и полностью состоит из изображения?(Python3, PyQt5)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1080839/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0).

Получил очень развернутый ответ со сложным для меня кодом. Когда я разбирал его, попытался сделать так, чтобы класс **Label** мог принимать путь к изображению в качестве аргумента, т.к. до этого путь был прописан внутри этого класса.

Это привело меня к ошибке:

> TypeError: QPixmap(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Window'

Пожалуйста, скажите, где я ошибся?

Я изменил код следующим образом:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, antialiasing=True): # <--- Аргумент picture, который
                                                # я хочу передать копии класса Label
                                                # в классе Window
        super(Label, self).__init__()
        self.picture = picture
        self.Antialiasing = antialiasing
        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)    

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled( # <--- Передаю аргумент picture методу QPixmap()
            140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        if self.Antialiasing:
            painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit() 


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.label = Label(self, 'picture1.png') # <--- Передаю путь
        self.label.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: green;")     

    def onClicked(self):
        print('Вы сделали клик')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не правильно передаете параметры

Замените `self.label = Label(self, 'picture1.png')`   на `self.label = Label('picture1.png', self)`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я уже час сижу над этим, не знал, что так передаются параметры